# Mobile push for Android using exacttarget's SDK doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, android, mobilepush

I'm trying to send push notifications from exacttarget's portal `mc.s7.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/MobilePush/MobilePush/` and it doesn't seem to work at all.

The device is not registered in the marketing cloud, I have no idea what I'm missing.
I presume something needs to be done on the marketing cloud portal for it to work.

**I followed the following steps:**
[Getting started with Android SDK](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/overview/getting-started.html)

In the Device itself everything looks ok. onETPushConfigurationSuccess is called with success and I verified many times that my AppId,AccessToken and GcmSenderId look OK.

Nevertheless, In the exacttarget portal itself, I dont see where the connection between the portal and the sdk is done. 
I'm trying to send messages and it doesn't seem to work.
I feel that i am missing something.

Here is the SDK configuration and I have attached the portal screen shots as well.

```
     ETPush.configureSdk(new ETPushConfig.Builder(this)
                        .setEtAppId("46aa756a-2640-4fd9-b232-??????????????")
                        .setAccessToken("csvgy7w7yppxyc7hec???????")
                        .setGcmSenderId("12376975????")
                        .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? Log.VERBOSE : Log.ERROR)
                        .setAnalyticsEnabled(ANALYTICS_ENABLED)
                        .setLocationEnabled(LOCATION_ENABLED)
                        .setPiAnalyticsEnabled(WAMA_ENABLED)
                        .setCloudPagesEnabled(CLOUD_PAGES_ENABLED)
                        .setProximityEnabled(PROXIMITY_ENABLED)
                        .build()
                , this // Our ETPushConfigureSdkListener


 @Override
public void onETPushConfigurationSuccess(ETPush etPush, ETRequestStatus etRequestStatus)

    mEtPush = etPush;

     // If there was an user recoverable issue with Google Play Services then show a notification to the user
    int googlePlayServicesStatus = etRequestStatus.getGooglePlayServiceStatusCode();
    if (googlePlayServicesStatus != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS && GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(googlePlayServicesStatus)) {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, googlePlayServicesStatus);
    }

    String sdkState;
    try {
        sdkState = ETPush.getInstance().getSDKState();
        etPush.setSubscriberKey("test@mycompany.com");
    } catch (ETException e) {
        sdkState = e.getMessage();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see the "SystemToken" in the log?  After you receive a SystemToken from Google you will see a Registration sent to the MC.  Registrations are aggregated and propagated to the internal systems about every 5 min.

Are you refreshing your audience list on send?

Can you see your device in the audience list?